# Tensorflow2 , Precision of SGD

Tags: python, tensorflow

formula: f(x) = 2x + 5

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_data = list(range(100))
y_data = [2 * n + 5 for n in x_data]

x = tf.Variable(0.0)

y = tf.Variable(0.0)

w = tf.Variable(0.0, name="w0")
b = tf.Variable(0.0, name="b0")

@tf.function
def pred():
    return tf.add(tf.multiply(x, w), b)

loss_func = lambda : tf.reduce_mean(tf.square( y - pred()))

optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0001)

for _ in range(20):
    for xs, ys in zip(x_data, y_data):
        x.assign(xs)
        y.assign(ys)
        optimizer.minimize(loss_func, var_list=[w, b])

print(w.numpy(), b.numpy())
```

result: w=2.0466027 b=0.36308017

According to the formula, b should near 5 but it is far away

does anybody know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with calculation precision. It is just not an optimal choice of optimizer and hyperparameters.

I tried `optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)` and in 100 iterations it estimated `b` close to 5 nicely.

I believe that in your example SGD will eventually yield estimate for `b` close to 5, but it will take way more than 20 epochs (1-2 thousands?). Raising learning rate will cause gradient explosion since you train the model on single datapoint at a time.  You may want to train model on whole batch of 100 datapoints at a time - this is where tensorflow will show its strength.